# Resource not opening Excel file in ax 2012

Tags: excel, batch-processing, axapta, aot, dynamics-ax-2012-r2

In my Ax 2012 have created one aot resource of type xlsx: a.xlsx as in the image below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tjg1R.png)

When I try to open and export the a.xlsx resource I cannot open it. It is no saved as a xlsx file.
I am trying to open the Resource that I have created by right clicking Open as below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wqz6w.png)
It opens the below window and I click export:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S4fmB.png)

I save the file in the folder, but it does not saved as an excel file(.xlsx).
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/viHMm.png)

Instead it is saved without a type:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ENq3T.png)

The same thing happens when I try to open any of the standard resources. It is not opened in the file format as defined in the resource.
I have not used resoruces before.
**Are there any parameters or configuration regarding the resources that I need to set , in order for the resources to work(to be opened)?**

In the meantime I do have Excel installed, and it does have the Dynamics AX addin installed, as in the image below
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MiqPT.png)

P.s. I am using this resource in order to export data in excel in batch thrugh OXMLSpreadsheetDoucment_RU, as indicated in the link below.
https://axbytes.blogspot.com/2015/12/readwrite-excel-files-from-aos-using.html

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to open the Resource that I have created by right clicking Open as below:

That's not how you open/save Excels. That form you're viewing is just a helper form that lets you import/export objects into the `Resources` node of the AOT for use by *other* code, typically.

The `Resources` node isn't designed to be used a file store for you to open/save/edit files. It's designed to be semi-permanent object storage that can be referenced/used by other code and it will travel with the AX codebase.

Look at the code inside the form method here `\Forms\SysResourceNodeEdit\Methods\export` and you'll see that when you click `Export`, it's asking you where you'd like to save the file with this line of code:

> `userInputPath = WinAPI::getSaveFileName(element.hWnd(), ['All Files', '*.*'], '', "@SYS54846", '', filenameOnly);`

It's designed as a simple import/export utility. You can modify that code if you'd like to make it save with the *actual* file extension by referring to what is returned in the `type` variable from the previous line of code.